# Data not showing in Swiftui using Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am using Swiftui and firebase database. I am not seeing any error or any data on the screen. I did install the Pods and checked the security rules as well in console. I tried couple other methods, but this was exactly same from youtube tutorials except the collection name and fields.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase



struct Calories: View {

    @ObservedObject var data = getData()

    var body: some View {

   NavigationView{

    ZStack(alignment: .top){

                        GeometryReader{_ in

                            // Home View....
                            Text("Home")

                        }.background(Color("Color").edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))

                        CustomSearchBar(data: self.$data.datas).padding(.top)

                    }.navigationBarTitle("")
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                }
            }
        }
struct Calories_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Calories()
    }
}

struct CustomSearchBar : View {

    @State var txt = ""
    @Binding var data : [dataType]

    var body : some View{

        VStack(spacing: 0){

            HStack{

                TextField("Search", text: self.$txt)

                if self.txt != ""{

                    Button(action: {

                        self.txt = ""

                    }) {

                        Text("Cancel")
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.black)

                }

            }.padding()

            if self.txt != ""{

                if  self.data.filter({$0.item.lowercased().contains(self.txt.lowercased())}).count == 0{

                    Text("No Results Found").foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.5)).padding()
                }
                else{

                List(self.data.filter{$0.item.lowercased().contains(self.txt.lowercased())}){i in

                NavigationLink(destination: Detail(data: i)) {

                        Text(i.item)
                    }


                    }.frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 5)
                }

            }


        }.background(Color.white)
        .padding()
    }
}


class getData : ObservableObject{

    @Published var datas = [dataType]()

    init() {

        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        db.collection("HSCal").getDocuments { (snap, err) in

            if err != nil{

                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            for i in snap!.documents{

                let id = i.documentID
                let item = i.get("item") as! String
                let cal = i.get("cal") as! String

                self.datas.append(dataType(id: id, item: item, cal: cal))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct dataType : Identifiable {

    var id : String
    var item : String
    var cal : String
}

struct Detail : View {

    var data : dataType

    var body : some View{

        Text(data.item)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you put app bundle?

try in

```
struct Calories: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var List: getData()
    ....
}
```

call

```
Calories().environmentObject(DataList)
```

declare somewhere

```
var DataList = getData()
```